# Spring Cloud Data Flow datasources overrides spring batch app datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm setting up an instance of Spring Cloud Data Flow. I've run the following commands:

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.9.2.jar \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=false \
--spring.cloud.dataflow.features.schedules-enabled=true \
--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/batch \
--spring.datasource.username=postgres \
--spring.datasource.password=postgres \
--spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver \
--spring.datasource.initialization_mode=always
```

I've developed a batch job using spring batch to be deployed in this platform. The job uses two data sources: batch for Spring and task Metadata and app_db for my business logic. When I run the app locally, it persists metadata in batch and my business data in app_db, as expected. The problem is when I try to execute de job inside the Spring Cloud Dataflow. The platform overrides my configured business logic database and uses only the batch database, which is supposed to store metadata only.

application.yaml

```
spring:
  batch:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/batch
      username: postgres
      password: postgres

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app_db
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
```

DatasourceConfiguration

```
public class DatasourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
 
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "batchDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.batch.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties batchDataSourceProperties() {
        return new BatchDataSourceProperties();
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "batchDataSource")
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return batchDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTask
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchApplication {

    @Bean
    public TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Job

```
@Bean
public Job startJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, DataSource dataSource) {
    try {                                   
        System.out.println(dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //TODO: handle exception
        }
}
```

When I look at the data source,`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app_db` will be printed when the batch is executed from local and `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/batch` will be printed when the batch (task) is executed from SCDF.

I want to know how dataflow is overriding application the spring.datasource even though I am not passing any arguments while executing the task. Please suggest a solution to avoid the overriding of datasource.
One solution I am thinking of is creating AppDatasourceConfiguration(app.datasource) use it. But is there a possibility to use spring.datasource without getting overiddien by SCDF.

Comment: According to the output of your log, SCDF is using the datasource that you specified in `--spring.datasource.url` as expected. You need to configure the step that is executing your business logic with the datasource pointing to `app_db`.